# Problem when Serving static files in Django

Tags: python, django, static

I have my css file in 
`/var/www/media/static/style.css`
 and added

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': '/var/www/media/static'}),
```

to my urls but when I go to http://localhost:8000/media/style.css I get: "Page not found: /media/style.css" what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the actual choice of Path: '/media' was taken by admin I changed it to '/static' that works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your settings.MEDIA_ROOT (the filesystem path) and settings.MEDIA_URL (the URL for static assets) to reflect the setup of your project?

Answer (score 0):

Check the logging output to see what's actually been requested - I've found that to be particularly helpful in diagnosing these issues.